# getting plist file location created by CFPreferences with kCFPreferencesAnyUser

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, core-foundation

I've started using `CFPreferences` in order to create persistent DB that can be shared between processes (just like registry in Windows)

If I set multiple values using `CFPreferencesSetMultiple` with userName argument as `kCFPreferencesAnyUser`, where does the file that represent the preferences is saved ?

In addition, it seems like I cannot trace this DB from Bash using `defaults read <my_bundle_id>` command, but from Objective-c code I successfully manage to get the dictionary with all the keys i just set using `CFPreferencesCopyMultiple`, any idea why ?

thanks

Comment: This is just a warning, `CFPreferences` (and `NSUserDefaults`) is not like the registry in Windows. Current versions of macOS have a great deal of difficulty, and sometimes outright refuse, to update the values in one process with the values set by a second process. So while I wish you luck, I suspect you're going to need to find a different solution. The solution I ultimately settled on was to have one process responsible for all of the shared values and the other processes get/set those values via XPC.

Comment: @jamesbucanek, thank you for enlightening with this knowledge, I actually just started dealing with this idea and I prefer not to waste my time for vain if it's not robust. I'd love to hear more about your proposed solution that involved XPC messages to a a separate process that handle the DB. I wonder how do you make it persistent and fault tolerant. does all the writes instantly saved in file ? if you get a message from several xpc queues, do you execute it serially ?

Comment: @jamesBucanek, following your suggestion, I've asked a relevant question about how to implement the XPC solution to achieve coherency and persistency. perhaps you can share your knowledge here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51756142/implementing-multi-process-shared-db-in-macos-using-xpc

Comment: Short story: I created my own "registry" by writing an app that runs as a registered XPC service. The calls are as simple as "setValue" and "getValue", which are nearly one-line functions that set/get said values in the preferences (`NSUserDefaults`) of the service app. I leave the serialization, updating, and synchronization to the preferences classes. The `NSUserDefaults` class is thread safe, so there are no concurrency problems.

Comment: Just another note maybe it could help you too.. did you use the `CFPreferences` set command followed by `CFPreferencesSynchronize` command, it should block the thread until the action has completed successfully.